# How to stream audio from Windows PC to Ubuntu over a network?

Tags: windows, sound, networking, stream

I have a Windows PC (don't worry, I almost never use it) that sometimes gets used for playing games and audio/video.

Is there a way I can stream the audio output from that PC over the network to my Ubuntu machine? Both PCs are on the same network, so they can reference themselves directly via their local IP addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AirFoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/) would probably be the best option. <strike>It's essentially a plugin for iTunes</strike> It's a whole-system audio redirector   that'll let you stream any audio to a whole host of destinations *including Linux*. It does come at rather a steep cost for a "utility" though: $25.

Failing that you might be able to run a radio-streaming app on your PC (these are ten-a-penny) and pick that up on your Ubuntu machine with a supported player. I'm fairly sure Banshee and Totem can pick up the audio.

I'm not sure these will handle more than two audio channels (or if that's even an requirement) but start your search with [ShoutCast](http://www.shoutcast.com/download) or its GPL brother from another mother: [IceCast](http://www.icecast.org/)

Comment: Hmmm... I never thought of a radio streamer. Good idea!

Comment: Is there anything like Ices for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind paying, there's a product called [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) made by [Rogue Amoeba](http://rogueamoeba.com/) to do just this. The setup requires an application to be installed on both machines. The [Airfoil for Windows](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/) application will allow audio streaming to any Airfoil Speaker application (.deb [here](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/linux/speakers.php)).

Note that the Linux application requires mono 1.2.6 or higher, and a full license of the Windows application is not free (currently $25). There is a free trial version available.

Answer (score 0):

IceS-ne for Windows (based on ices 0.4 + new features):
http://hobbes.nmsu.edu/h-search.php?key=ices-ne&pushbutton=Search

Comment: Could you expand on how one would utilize this source client for broadcasting to an Icecast server (OS/2 and Windows versions) to resolve the question? For instance what would be the requirements on the Ubuntu side and how would one fulfill those? Thank you.

Comment: It works just as as ICES for other OSes. No special "windows-oriented" requirements on the server side. See readme.txt, comments in ices.conf and README files included in this archive.

Answer (score 0):

I've altered a program found on internet and created [WLStream](https://github.com/rsegecin/WLStream). It enables you to stream audio from a Windows output device so Pulse Audio will be able to play it back on a Linux host. The communication between the two is done with plink from Putty. There's a delay in the audio stream caused by the network, I'm sure if you alter the privilege on the TCP packet sent from plink or change your router's configuration as you would for VOIP it'll reduce the audio's stream lag but my research didn't go any further. WLStream can be compiled using Visual Studio 2017 and there's a pre-compiled from the last version [here](https://github.com/rsegecin/WLStream/tree/Published).